# pouchdb doesn't create remote db on nginx server on Sync resulting lots of 404 on GETs and POSTs

Tags: nginx, couchdb, pouchdb

I have added a basic authentication on localCouchDb (http://localhost:5984/testdb). And sync works fine with credentials.

On remoteCouchdb (http:***remote_ip***/testdb) which I've configured on nginx with below snippet:

```
server {
    listen         80 default_server;
    listen         [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name    myDomain.com www.myDomain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5984;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }


        location ~ ^/(.*)/_changes {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5984;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

I have enabled ***WWW-Authenticate = Basic realm="administrator"*** for both local and remote couchDb in **local.ini** file.

On remoteCouchDb too I have the same credentials which seems to be working. But at the time of sync operation, I'm getting growing number of errors like below:

```
GET http://***remote_ip***/testdb/_local/x8B36az7Yezgye.7zCNXwA%3D%3D? 404  
POST http://***remote_ip***/testdb/_revs_diff 404 (Object Not Found)
```

It looks like, sync operation is not able to create **testdb** on remote. Verified by hitting 'http://***remote_ip***/testdb'.

I can visit Futon page both on localCouchDb (http://localhost:5984/_utils/), and remoteCouchDb (http://***remote_ip***/_utils/).

Only difference is the version of couchDb; on local, couchDb version is "1.6.0" and on remote it is "1.6.1". Is this is a problem or have I missed any configuration on remoteCouchDb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm embarrassed with the question I asked, I found the solution. Unlike couchdb 1.6.0, you have to create the database in 1.6.1, in fact same for 2.1.2 (So I guess from version 1.6.1 we need to create the database on our own in the beginning).